# Name lookup issue in trailing return type

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, argument-dependent-lookup, trailing-return-type

The following example illustrates my question:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
auto func(const T& x) -> decltype(to_string(x)) {
  using std::to_string;
  return to_string(x);
}

int main() {
  std::cout << func(1);
}
```

I don't want to import `std::to_string` into global namespace, not do I want to use `-> decltype(std::to_string(x))` as doing this disables ADL. Obviously, you can't put `using std::to_string` within `decltype`. So, how should I do it?

Comment: You have C++14 in tags. If you are using C++14, you do not need trailing return type at all. Just leave `auto`.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That will disable SFINAE, and if SFINAE is not needed, (in this specific case) one can just use `std::string` as the return type.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Defer to another namespace;

```
namespace activate_adl {
  using std::to_string;
  template <typename T>
  auto func(const T& x) -> decltype(to_string(x)) {
    return to_string(x);
  }
}

template <typename T>
auto func(const T& x) -> decltype(activate_adl::func(x)) {
  return activate_dl:: func(x);
}
```

This allows the ADL to still be done, but doesn't pollute you global namespace.

Having hit this issue a few times with some `std` related functions and ADL, I've found the deferred namespace (well named) is be suitable alternatives.